# How to handle NULL values in mysql/php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, null

In MSSQL Server, we make queries for null values like below:

```
SELECT name, ISNULL(about, ''), contact FROM `user_profile` WHERE userid=1
```

But when I am trying to do the same with MYSQL then it gives error.

What is the logical and easy way to handle NULL values in php/mysql scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's IFNULL() for MySQL ^^
But in your case it seems you can return a NULL value, just use a condition to test it.

```
if(!$result['valuemaybenull']) -> true if 0, false or NULL
```

Comment: Yes, its resolved and I am trying to accept it as answer but don't know why SO keep saying "wait for 6 minutes".. will accept it after 6 minutes.. :)

Comment: ^^ I don't know enough yet stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Be cautios about the following in MySQL:

SELECT 1=NULL  returns NULL
SELECT 1!=NULL return NULL (as well)

Whenever you want to check for null values use the     IS NULL expression (or the above IFNULL)